# How to configure a eclipse project to use Kotlin with JPA/Hibernate?

Tags: eclipse, kotlin

I have installed Kotlin in Eclipse (it must be Eclipse, not JetBrains) and started a Kotlin project with no problem. Now I want to add JPA support to such a project, but I can't add any already existing Kotlin classes to my `persistent.xml`.

Here is one of those classes, alread annotated to be persisted:

```
package my.project.domain

import java.util.Date
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table
import javax.persistence.Temporal
import javax.persistence.TemporalType

@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
open class Person(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id_person")
    var Id: Long? = null,
    @Column(name = "name", length = 150, nullable = false)
    var Name: String? = null,
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "creation_date", nullable = false)
    var CreationDate: Date? = null) {
}
```

My dependencies in `pom.xml` are:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.4-3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>11.2.0.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In my `persistence.xml` I want add a reference like this:

```
<class>my.project.domain.Person</class>
```

However, I keep receiving an error that stated such a class cannot be resolved. That class is located in a source folder named `/src/main/kotlin` and the file name is `Person.kt`.

What to do?

Comment: Is that exactly where the class is or is it in the proper directory hierarchy?

Comment: @DaveNewton: in the project explorer I have a source folder named `/src/main/kotlin`. Inside that source folder I have a package named `my.project.domain` and inside that package I have the `Person.kt`file. In the filesystem I find my source file in the `<project directoty>\src\main\kotlin\my\project\domain`.